# Import to FileNet using the bulk import tool in a specific folder

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet-content-engine, bulk-import

I'm trying to use the FileNet bulkimport.jar file to upload a huge number of files to the FileNet, but it always upload to "Unfiled Documents" folder, so is there any way to change the path where the tool uploads?

Also i tried to put the "Folders Filed In" property in the documents class attributes in the CEBI.cfg file but this property is Read-Olny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Filenet Subscription on Documents with "checkIn" event.
You can move the imported documents to any folder you can calculate from Class Definition or any other property value.